# I am trying to build a website according to the "Holy Grail Layout" and I cannot get it to look good on my phone

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am building a website using the [Holy Grail Layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_grail_(web_design)) and while it looks fine currently on my laptop and desktop computers, it looks terrible on my phone and does not resize correctly at all. I cannot even see half of the page despite having a media query to try and address this as well as using dynamically sized HTML elements in the rest of my CSS. Here is my code, I am not sure what my issue is currently as my media query doesn't seem to do anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script>
const originalAlpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
// rot13
var rot13 = function() {
    var the_text = document.getElementById("main_text").value;
    the_text = the_text.replace(/[a-z]/gi, letter => String.fromCharCode(letter.charCodeAt(0) + (letter.toLowerCase() <= 'm' ? 13 : -13)));
    document.getElementById("output_text").innerHTML=the_text;
};
</script>
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Baskerville&family=ZCOOL+QingKe+HuangYou&display=swap');

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Use a media query to add a breakpoint at 800px: */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    html, body {
        aspect-ratio: 1024/768;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}

.item1 { grid-area: header; }
.item2 { grid-area: menu; }
.item3 { grid-area: main; }
.item4 { grid-area: right; }
.item5 { grid-area: footer; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header header header header'
    'menu main main main right right'
    'menu footer footer footer footer footer';
  gap: 10px;
  background-color:seashell;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgb(57, 61, 66, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.plaintext-form {
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    align-content:center;
    text-align: justify;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 2%;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', sans-serif;
}

ul {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    position: relative;
    justify-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-content: center;
    width: auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}

li {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 21px;
}

a {
    color:slateblue;
}

p {
    background-color: rgb(57, 61, 66, 0.4);
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align:justify;
    color:gainsboro;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', sans-serif;
}

footer {
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    align-content:center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 2%;
    padding: 2%;
}
</style>
<title>ROT13 Cipher Machine</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">
    <h1 class="page_title">ROT13 Cipher Machine</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    <div class="navbar">
        <header role="navigation">
            <nav class="site-nav">
                <ul id="site-links">
                    <li id="homework"><a href="./cs212/homework/">Homework</a></li>
                    <li id="crypto"><a href="./docs/Cryptography/index.html">Cryptography</a></li>
                    <!-- <li id="networking"><a href="./docs/network-programming.html">Network Programming</a></li>
                    <li id="quantum-computing"><a href="./docs/quantum-computing.html">Quantum Computing</a></li> -->
                    <li id="minecraft"><a href="./docs/minecraft.html">Minecraft</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item3">
        <form id="input_text">
            Plaintext/Ciphertext: <input class="plaintext-form" type="text" placeholder="Type" id="main_text"><br><br>
            <input type="button" onclick="rot13()" value="Submit">
        </form>
  </div>  
  <div class="item4">
        <h4>Output:</h4>
        <p id="output_text"></p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="item5">
    <section class="rot13-about">
        The ROT13 Algorithm is a symmetric cipher algorithm; simply put:
        <br><br>
        <code>
        ROT13(plaintext) = ciphertext, rot13(ciphertext) = plaintext 
        </code>
        <br><br>
        Try it out yourself for some simple text obfuscation!
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I personally prefer flexboxes over CSS grid and find the grid to be terribly confusing. Maybe I am using it wrong, but I have to use both for my assignment.

Edit: I added a 600px breakpoint and it still cuts off over half the screen, this can be seen in the screenshot below.

[phone screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BW8U.png)

I am so tired of making sites that should fit with responsive design practices and then seeing them never work for me. I have media queries, I have dynamic sizing with %'s, I have a combo of a grid and flexboxes. Nothing about that should cause it to cut half my site off on mobile screens and I cannot understand what would be the cause at this point. Everything I look up indicates these are the things I should be doing to make it responsive yet it never works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your media query only has one break point at 800px;

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    html, body {
        aspect-ratio: 1024/768;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

You would need to add another break point for cell phone screens such as

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    html, body {
        ...
    }
}
```

Cell phone screen size break points can be anywhere between 400 to 600.

Comment: I had tested it with 600px too and it had the same result, I just added both and it still cuts off over half of my site for some reason on phones.  Is there some other thing which could be affecting this? the media queries strangely don't even seem to be affecting anything

Comment: smartphones in portaite mode only have a width of 320px - 480px. Breakpoints between 400-600px mostlikely going to be inusfficient for many smartphones. You need to include at least one breakpoint that works fine at a width of 320px.

Comment: That is because you have to change the CSS to be 400px friendly within the media query. You can't just put 600px with the same CSS inside it. For example you don't want an aspect-ratio of 1024/768 on a cell phone so you would change that among other things.

Comment: well I removed the aspect-ratio when I added the 600px query but I will try to make one for 400 and 320 with different ratios and see what I get.

Comment: Like I am adding queries for 600 px, 400px and 320px; all with respective ratios to match their phone screen sizes, it still does nothing and has half of the screen cut off. I have no clue what they are even doing because nothing changes between screens. Like I cannot even scroll right to see the missing content, it is simply gone and cuts off halfway through my main element. I also know the query should be in effect as the screen size I am testing is 375x812.

Comment: The answer to my problem ended up being the fact I had hardcoded multiple padding and margin values using pixels rather than percentages. After I fixed these to be percentages it solved my media query problem. Thank you for the help, I think I have a better grasp on responsive design from this, albeit it was frustrating.